# Set up background image using Image View in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

The app will always be in portrait mode, and I want to set an image as the background using an Image View. The entire width of the image needs to fit the width of the screen, and the aspect ratio should stay the same. The top and bottom of the image can "bleed over" and not be visible. "Aspect Fit" doesn't help me because the top and bottom are fully shown, causing the image width not fit the screen width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Autolayout` in your storyboard? Add an `UIImageView` and select **Pin**. Here you can choose your values of the positioning.

[image]

Or you can use code

```
let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR IMAGE NAME")
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Great, it's mostly working! The image is centered on screen, not filling the bottom of the screen and filling part of the status bar at the top.

Comment: Are the image big enough? You could use negative values for X, Y, but make sure that the image is big enough otherwise it will never fill the background.